# Why doesn't Roo generate Spring repository query methods for finder

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I am using spring roo to develop a small web application. I used the finder commands to add few finder APIs. After removing Roo with Push-in, the code generated is following in the model class

```
public static TypedQuery<Task> findTasksByAssignedTo(Employee assignedTo) {
    if (assignedTo == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The assignedTo argument is required");
    EntityManager em = Task.entityManager();
    TypedQuery<Task> q = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM Task AS o WHERE o.assignedTo = :assignedTo", Task.class);
    q.setParameter("assignedTo", assignedTo);
    return q;
}
```

Why doesn't Roo just generate findBy methods in the Repository interface? Or does it support something like this that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by default Roo use the [Active Record Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) and does not use DAOs.

Active Record Pattern:

> An object that wraps a row in a database table or view, **encapsulates the database access**, and adds domain logic on that data."

Comment: Thanks for the info. I would then rephrase my question, why Roo use Active record pattern and not DAO? Isn't DAO much simpler? may be I should ask it as a separate question

Comment: Then your question would not meet the stack overflow requirements for an question, and would be looked or closed, because then it is "primarily opinion-based"